# Android Studio - When I launch my app and navigate to a menu, the buttons go to an empty Screen instead of the activity

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

When I open my app and navigate through my menus, I come to a page with multiple buttons. Each button is meant to send data to another activity and then launch it. It can send the data alright but when I hit the button, it takes me to a blank page. When I hit the back button on my phone, it shows me the right screen. I have added plain text which shows up on the blank screen but the textViews dont appear until I hit the back Button.

activity java file:

```
package com.example.boys.fishkeeper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Categories extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button barbsButton;
    private Button tetrasButton;
    private Button livebearersButton;
    private Button gouramisButton;
    private Button cichlidsButton;
    private Button bettasButton;
    private Button rasborasButton;
    private Button daniosButton;
    private Button snakeheadsButton;
    private Button mormyridsButton;
    private Button catfishButton;
    private Button knifefishButton;
    private Button loachesButton;
    private Button pufferfishButton;
    private Button plecsButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);

        barbsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.barbsButton);
        tetrasButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tetrasButton);
        livebearersButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.livebearersButton);
        gouramisButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gouramisButton);
        cichlidsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cichlidsButton);
        bettasButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bettaButton);
        rasborasButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rasborasButton);
        daniosButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.daniosButton);
        snakeheadsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.snakeheadsButton);
        mormyridsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mormyridsButton);
        catfishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.catfishButton);
        knifefishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.knifefishButton);
        loachesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loachesButton);
        pufferfishButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pufferfishButton);
        plecsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plecsButton);

        barbsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Barbs");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        bettasButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Bettas");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Betta are incredibly aggresive towards their own species. They will fight each other to the death. Plankat betta may survive with tetra and catfish but siamese fighters can only be kept singly(as a male) or in species tanks(if they are female).");

                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        tetrasButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Tetras");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        livebearersButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Livebearers");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Livebearers give birth to live young and are hardy fish. They are usually small(less than 6 cm)");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        gouramisButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Gouramis");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        cichlidsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Cichlids");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }



        });
        rasborasButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Rasboras");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        daniosButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Danios");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        snakeheadsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Snakeheads");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        mormyridsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "MormyRids");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        catfishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Catfish");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        knifefishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "KnifeFish");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Gouramis");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        loachesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Loaches");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Loaches have an erectable spine below their eyes. They genrally grow quite large and benefit from living in groups.");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        pufferfishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "PufferFish");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "They are cool!");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });
        plecsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Plecs");
                intent.putExtra("typeInfo", "Plecs are cool!");
                startActivity(intent);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
                startActivity(i);




            }
        });


    }
}
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.boys.fishkeeper.FishInfo">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameOfFish"
        android:layout_width="317dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fishInfo"
        android:layout_width="314dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Info"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameOfFish" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You could have avoid a lot of duplication in your code just be implementing onCick in your class

Comment: you have *two* `startActivity` per click. why is that?

Comment: can you post xml code with buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the same activity twice and second time, it has no data, hence the issue so remove

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
intent.putExtra("typeName", "Barbs");
// or other data
startActivity(intent);

// start FishInfo activity with no data
// remove every occurrence of this 
//Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FishInfo.class);
//startActivity(i);
```

Comment: So is **Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("typeName", "Barbs");
                startActivity(intent); **  enough to launch it as well?

Comment: @B.Sommer yes, you need only one instance of `Intent` to start a particular activity, either with data or without

Answer (score 0):

You are running activity twice: once with extra data, and once without. So, what you are describing is right behavior.
Replace the `onClick()` method with:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FishInfo.class);
   intent.putExtra("typeName", "Barbs");
   startActivity(intent);    
}
```

This will send data and start your activity.